# Emmet coding lorem ipsum, not starting with lorem

Tags: emmet, lorem-ipsum

Well I just started with emmet scripting/coding. So I found out you can easily generate lorem ipsum

```
div>lorem20
```

Only problem I am having I am using lots of lorem ipsum and every thing on the page starts with `lorem ipsum`. I tried to look if there is a way to say i want lorem ipsum but not starting with lorem ipsum and I can't find any answer to this question.

So the question is, can I easily generate lorem ipsum with emmet but don't let it start with lorem ipsum. (I know that I can remove it but that would be a waste of the syntax using

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It might be a new version now. But if I try it (in PHPStorm) with

```
div>lorem5*10
```

I get

```html
<div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div>Ea ipsam laboriosam recusandae voluptatibus?</div>
    <div>Animi laborum nam quaerat sequi!</div>
    <div>Obcaecati quos ratione tempora totam.</div>
    <div>Aspernatur porro possimus repellat suscipit?</div>
    <div>Harum incidunt ipsam iste vero?</div>
    <div>Architecto dolorem magni numquam voluptas?</div>
    <div>Porro recusandae totam ut veritatis.</div>
    <div>Dolorum earum laudantium magnam maiores.</div>
    <div>Non obcaecati sit veritatis voluptatibus.</div>
</div>
```

Every sentence starts with a different text.

Comment: It should be  `div>(div>lorem5)*10` in linux+vim+emmet.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a copy of [Lorem Ipsum generator](https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/blob/master/javascript/generators/lorem-ipsum.js) and put it into [Extensions folder](http://docs.emmet.io/customization/).

In your copy of generator, update `paragraph()` function: simply set `startWithCommon = false;` somewhere at the top of function body.

Comment: I accept the answer because it is right, unfortunately I couldn't find how to do it in PHPstorm

Comment: PHPStorm uses its own implementation of Emmet so it doesn’t support all features of original project.

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the solution is needed for PHPstorm, I'd like to post a solution for Sublime Text 3. I haven't found anything on the Internet for this problem:

```
1. Write a js-File into the extensions location defined in your `Emmet.sublime-settings` File.
   (the default path is ~/emmet, which is a folder called "emmet" in your OS-user directory)
2. Copy the following code into the file and save:
```

.

```
emmet
    .require('lorem')
    .addLang('en', ['all', 'the', 'words', 'you', 'want', 'to', 'use']);
```

You could also define another language, but I haven't found out, how to change this setting. Maybe it's the Editor's language. This will simply overwrite the default language.