# How can I get the first line of emmet's "lorem ipsum" generator to be random, not always "Lorem ipsum..."?

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet, lorem-ipsum

So yes, I'm aware that I can type `lorem5*3<tab>` to get emmet to generate 3 lines of text where the last 2 lines are always random. Unfortunately, the FIRST line is always the same: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet." I'm currently trying to replace random manually-written text in a pre-existing HTML file with random "lorem ipsum" generated content instead, but I obviously don't want every instance to begin with "Lorem ipsum". Is there a trick to doing this in VSCode? Perhaps a configuration setting that tells emmet to always *begin* randomly? I need a way to either suppress the first line or to make it random.

Ideally, I'd be able to do this with VSCode's built-in Emmet, but an extension as a fallback would be fine, too.

Comment: The point of using lipsum is that you don't care what the text is saying. If you do care, then you should be using something else

Comment: emmet is written in JS and you can modify the Lorem generator, be aware if you update VSC

Comment: @rioV8 Yeah, someone already mentioned that option [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17511090/10818186). I'd really rather not do that, though. I'd probably have to constantly update it as new versions of VSCode come out and overwrite my changes.

Answer (score 4):

Your concern is valid and luckily there's a solution, that can be found in the official [Emmet documentation](https://docs.emmet.io/customization/preferences/). In `preferences.json`, this configuration is by default set to `false`:

> **lorem.omitCommonPart**
> Omit commonly used part (e.g. “Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet“) from generated text.

So it seems the solution is to set it to `true`, isn't it? Simply, yay!

Not really, actually we're talking about VSCode. There's no support to this functionality yet  according to their [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet). Thus, since this customization is not supported, they advise:

> If you want support for any of the other preferences as documented in Emmet Preferences, please log a [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new)

So if you don't mind waiting try logging that request and your problem may be addressed sooner or later (or never)

Comment: Great find. Thanks. :) I will submit that preference setting as a VSCode feature request tomorrow.